# post data to api using json

Tags: php, json, api, post, curl

This code i wrote to send data to an api using post method in JSON but in response i am getting invalid can anyone tell me what is wrong in the code.

```
$post = array(
    "operatorCode"=>"9",
    "scheduleCode"=>"84W92XC8LOBAF3KZP4",
    "travelDate"=>"2015-03-20",
    "fromStationCode"=>"84",
    "toStationCode"=>"76",
    "boardingPointCode"=>"191933",
    "droppingPointCode"=>"0000",
    "email"=>"*********",
    "mobile"=>"*******",
    "passenger"=>array(
                    "seatNumber"=>"40",
                    "name"=>"*****",
                    "age"=>"20",
                    "gender"=>"Male"
                 )
);

$data_string = json_encode($post);
echo $data_string;   
$ch=url_init('http://api?username=*****');   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('data'=>$data_string));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);
var_dump($result);
echo'<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Response From api

```
stdClass Object
(
   [code] => 0
   [errorCode] => ER30
   [errorDesc] => Invalid Data
   [message] => Failure
)
```

Sample URL:

```
http://<ServerName>/bookbustickets/rest/json/2.0/tempbooking?username=****&password‌​=******
```

Sample Input data:

```
 data={"operatorCode":"2586", 
       "scheduleCode":"7Q52586C3YG8KJ350F2F5V264", 
       "travelDa‌​te":"2015-03-10", 
       "fromStationCode":"76", 
       "toStationCode":"75", 
       "boardingPointCode":‌​"284936", 
       "droppingPointCode":"0000",
       "email":"test@gmail.com",
       "mobile":"9876543210‌​",
       "passenger":[
                     {
                        "seatNumber":"3",
                        "na 9 me":"Test",
                        "age":20,
                        "gender":"Male"},
                      {
                        "seatNumber":"4",
                        "name":"Test",
                        "age":20,
                        "g‌​ender":"Male"}
                    ]
        }
```

Comment: Be more specific about the error message. Is it a curl error or an error returned from the API?

Comment: Response is coming but it is saying invalid data and failure

Comment: Response FROM WHERE???? Show the responce in your question EDIT YOUR QUESTIONS dont put it in a comment

Comment: response from the api

Comment: Screen shot the result here. If it is curl error try to learn how to use `curl_error`  http://php.net/curl_error also `curl_errno` http://php.net/curl-errno

Comment: Look up `ER30` in the documentation. You have not told us what API you are using so we cannot help with what that means.

Comment: i have edited the code with response

Comment: invalid data is mentioned in the documentation.for ER30

Comment: Only guessing but `"droppingPointCode"=>"0000"` code of `0000` may well be it? But as the writer of the API has not been very helpful with the error messages, **it could be anything** I would contact the API developer and give them a rocket.

Comment: Sample URL: http://<ServerName>/bookbustickets/rest/json/2.0/tempbooking?username=****&password=******
Sample Input data:
data={"operatorCode":"2586","scheduleCode":"7Q52586C3YG8KJ350F2F5V264","travelDate":"2015-03-10","fromStationCode":"76","toStationCode":"75","boardingPointCode":"284936","droppingPointCode":"0000","email":"test@gmail.com","mobile":"9876543210","passenger":[{"seatNumber":"3","na
9
me":"Test","age":20,"gender":"Male"},{"seatNumber":"4","name":"Test","age":20,"gender":"Male"}]}

Comment: in api this the format mentioned to how to send the data

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is that `"passenger"` should be an array of objects so try changing your code to

```
$passenger1 = new stdClass();
$passenger1->seatNumber = "40";
$passenger1->name = "*****";
$passenger1->age = "20";
$passenger1->gender = "Male";

$passenger2 = new stdClass();
$passenger2->seatNumber = "41";
$passenger2->name = "*****";
$passenger2->age = "21";
$passenger2->gender = "Female";

$post = array(
    "operatorCode"=>"9",
    "scheduleCode"=>"84W92XC8LOBAF3KZP4",
    "travelDate"=>"2015-03-20",
    "fromStationCode"=>"84",
    "toStationCode"=>"76",
    "boardingPointCode"=>"191933",
    "droppingPointCode"=>"0000",
    "email"=>"*********",
    "mobile"=>"*******",
    "passenger"=>array( $passenger1, $passenger2 )
);
```

This will generate the following result

```
{
   "operatorCode":"9",
   "scheduleCode":"84W92XC8LOBAF3KZP4",
   "travelDate":"2015-03-20",
   "fromStationCode":"84",
   "toStationCode":"76",
   "boardingPointCode":"191933",
   "droppingPointCode":"0000",
   "email":"*********",
   "mobile":"*******",
   "passenger":[
       { 
          "seatNumber":"40",
          "name":"*****",
          "age":"20",
          "gender":"Male"
       },
       {
          "seatNumber":"41",
          "name":"*****",
          "age":"21",
          "gender":"Female"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also I am note sure why you are using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

Would not

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

be a better option?

Comment: Thank you for your response but still the same problem i think there is a problem in how i am sending the data.

Comment: i think problem is somewhere in this line
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('data'=>$data_string));`